# Android Wear TextRenderer does not fill the bounds

Tags: android, wear-os, textrenderer

I'm trying out the fairly new TextRenderer in the Android wear support library whilst making a watch face app.

In the onDraw method, I call setText, and then I call draw and pass in the bounds from the parent onDraw method (280x280).

```
    String text = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
    textRenderer.setText(text);
    textRenderer.draw(canvas, bounds);
```

Unfortunately the text being printed out is tiny, it's super hard to find examples out there. 
[image]

I've read through the reference page and the solution is not coming to me.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/complications/rendering/TextRenderer.html

Comment: I'm reading the docs as saying that the bounds simply limit the drawn text; they don't really determine the size, apart from shrinking it to fit a minimal number of characters, apparently. You'd still need to set an appropriate text size on the `TextPaint` object, I believe.

Comment: Yup, I'm a wally. I made a bad assumption that this would work like the new TextView on Android that resizes the text to fill the widget size. This works the other way around :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [set a TextPaint on the TextRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/complications/rendering/TextRenderer.html#setPaint(android.text.TextPaint)) and it will use the text size of that TextPaint object as the initial size of your text.